# jQuery UI Dialog Box - Problem when using Firefox

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery-ui, firefox

I have some simple jQuery that renders a page in my Rails app.  Here's the jQuery:

```
$('a.popup').click(function() {
    $('<div />').appendTo('body').load($(this).attr('href') + ' form').dialog({
        title: $(this).text(),
        width: 425,
        position: 'top',
    });
    return false;
});
```

and here is the associated HTML, with ERB (embedded Ruby), generating the anchor tag:

```
<p><%= link_to "Add User", new_user_path, :class => "popup" %></p>
```

Anyhow, the problem is: it works in Chrome, displaying the correct page within the dialog.  With Firefox, the dialog box has no content, only a title ("Add User").

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: Are there any javascript errors in Firefox? What version of JQuery?

Comment: Verify your markup. IE and occasionally FF will give up rendering if there are not matching div tags, etc.

Comment: @Captain, Interesting..let me check.  @ddagradi, 1.4.2.

Comment: No markup problems.  Any ideas?

Comment: I see you have a space before 'form'
.load($(this).attr('href') + ' form')

Comment: @Harborhoffer: `.load()` allows you to append a selector to the URL to automatically extract just a chunk of the returned HTML, see "Loading Page Fragments" on http://api.jquery.com/load

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to say without a live example but maybe you have a timing issue with the asynchronous AJAX call. Try building the dialog in a callback:

```
$('a.popup').click(function() {
    var $a   = $(this);
    var $dlg = $('<div/>');
    $dlg.load($a.attr('href') + ' form', function() {
        $dlg.dialog({
            title:    $a.text(),
            width:    425,
            position: 'top'
        });
    });
    return false;
});
```

This way the whole content will be available before you hand things off to jQuery-UI.